# How to match all characters after nth character with regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all characters after 8th character. And not include first 8!

I need exactly a regular expression cause a framework (Ace.js) requires a regexp, not a string. So, this is not an option:

```
var substring = "123456789".substr(5);
```

Can I match everything after nth character using regex in JavaScript?

**Updates:** I can't call `replace()`, `substring()` etc because I don't have a string. The string is known at run time and I don't have access to it. As I already said above the framework (Ace.js) asks me for a regex.

Comment: Why don't you use `.{8}` in front of the rest of your regex?

Comment: You can't. This would require a lookbehind assertion which javascript doesn't support.

Comment: @thg435, yes, I've read about that. So, there is no other way?

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi: I'd look into their source code how they're using the regex. Is it always `match(...)[0]`?

Comment: @thg435, to create custom highlight mode https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode I need to pass regex to it and I'm unable to modify their source code. Ho could I? Suppose I will need to reference it from cdn.

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi: well, the docs state that the `token` can be a function, so you must be able to match the input against `/(.{8})(.+)/` and then simply drop the first group in `token()`.

Comment: @thg435, that's a token. I need to get value for 'regex' property.

Answer (score 20):

```
(?<=^.{8}).*
```

will match everything after the 7th position. Matches **89** in 0123456789

or **IJKLM** in ABCDEFGHIJKLM

etc

Answer (score 5):

```
console.log("123456789".match(/^.{8}(.*)/)[1])
```

Comment: /.{8}/ this selects a whole string if it's length >= 8. Check my question again please. I don't have access to the string, I need a regex, so I'm unable to use match(), subtr() or other methods